# Javascript not acquiring dropdown value

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 2 values in dropdown list as...

```
      <select id="prop">
          <option value="Caa:123">Ca</option>
          <option value="Cb:745">Cb</option>
      </select>
```

...and in javascript i used...

```
       var p = document.getElementById('prop');
       var q = p.options[p.selectedIndex].value;
       alert(q);
```

...but  I am not getting no alert and an error "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount" code: "1  "
                  Kindly help I trapped in this problem

Comment: Your code works fine.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wwZ6K/

Comment: Which browser are you testing it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var p = document.getElementById('prop');
var q = p.value;
alert(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't in your questions specifications, but I would use jQuery. It definitely is much more easier to handle and looks neater:

```
<select id="prop">
    <option value="Caa:123">Ca</option>
    <option value="Cb:745">Cb</option>
</select>
<script>
    alert($('#prop').val());

    $('#prop').change(function () {
        alert($('#prop').val());
    });
</script>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/czFzC/) ]**</sup>